# How to run Play Framework evolutions when deploying as a war file

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Is there any way to run the Play Framework evolutions when deploying a Play Framework 1.2.x application as a war file?  Specifically, I'm trying to get our app running on the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk architecture and the database evolutions piece is a key component of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's apparently not supported when you package your application in a WAR file. Some people have solved this issue by disabling the evolutions and writing their own plugin that runs the script automatically regardless of whether you're in DEV or PROD mode.

Comment: That's the conclusion we came to as well.  As a result we're running evolutions:apply directly from our build server and then building and deploying the war file as a separate step.  It's not ideal but it gets the job done.